# Migrated questions don't update comments' owners

Tags: bug, comments, migration

At least I think that's what's going on. As seen here:
[Is working on a side project considered working behind a team's back](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/16632/5008)

And for the clicky impaired:

> [image: wonky usernames]

The first handful of comments' usernames don't link to their profile, and the title of the username says "0 reputation". Since this question was migrated, my gut tells me those comments occurred before migration, but since the OP claimed his question after migration and has his new account linked to the original account, shouldn't those links update to be associated with the new account? A little nit-picky to be sure, but very confusing at first. It certainly *looks* like a bug, even if it's a cleverly disguised feature.